# Looking for USB IR receiver recommendations

Tags: usb, wireless, remote-control, htpc

Here is the plan.

I will be doing some research into some USB IR receivers for my girlfriend's HTPC as a fallback method if for some reason Kore (the Android app for KODI) drops in terms of connection.

It must support kernel 4.15 or lower, or have some drivers that can be installed. While I do this research I am curious to see if anybody has had success with such products.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If you have the know-how the hardware can be made with an Arduino + IR receiver on a breadboard. Maybe take a look on GitHub for some [projects like this](https://github.com/corbanmailloux/ArduinoKodiIRRemote).

Answer (score 2):

I use [Flirc USB](https://flirc.tv/more/flirc-usb) hardware and software on Ubuntu to control Kodi from my Logitech Harmony remote and have done for many years. It has Kodi profile in it's software so if you have a Logitech programmable remote or something it's nearly plug-and-play. But it can also be programmed from other remotes etc.

I don't know anything about the Kernel requirements though.

Comment: This is extremely good to know! not to worry I can do some research on the device that's no worries, appreciate the recommendation. Thank you!